# Android: null variable crashes app after background and no notification

Tags: android, memory

my app crashes ocassionally. Now I found out that it happenes if the device running some other memory consuming programs when I put it into background. When I put it back (without bringing any other app to foreground in the error case) I have some variables which are null.
onSaveInstanceState is called when I bring it to background as assumed but I do not get onRestoreInstanceState nor onCreate. 
If I start some other apps inbetween these methods get called.

I dont know why this happens and how I should handle parts of my memory getting void. I dont want to check for null every time.

Comment: What variables are they? Unless they are stored in permanent memory somewhere, you can't guarantee that they won't be destroyed

Comment: It'a bigger ArrayList. It's okay that the variable gets wiped out. I save it onSaveInstanceState. I could restore it but I don't have a handle when it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

How I handled it in an app where I needed certain static data structures is I looked for the flag in the intents which specified the app was restarting from background and when that occured I launched my launcher activity and finished the current one-  effectively rebooting the app.